# Transfer ownership after leaving multiplayer room

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

In our multiplayer app based on `Unity` and `PUN`, we have disabled `autoCleanUpPlayerObjects`, because it was destroying some necessary objects . Now, when player leaves room, ownership of those objects  get transferred to scene, which prevents user to control those objects even in single player mode.

We tried manually transferring ownership to self after leaving room, which works but throws this error:

```
Operation failed: OperationResponse 253: ReturnCode: -2 (Unknown operation code). Parameters: {} Server: MasterServer
```

How can we get around this problem without destroying PhotonView and other networking components and adding them each time multiplayer mode starts?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] when asking.

Comment: The error means you are trying to call an operation (253 = RaiseEvent, which is called under the hood for all PUN's specific stuff) on the Master Server (not joined to a room) which is not supported, hence the operation code is unknown to the server.

Comment: But I have to manually transfer ownership to self after leaving room, since I don't have another option. Will these errors have any side effect? Can this be by any chance a Photon bug, since PhotonTransformView should not be overriding transforms when user has left room, especially if observeOption of PhotonView is off?